# Vue 3 calling method dynamically without 'this'

Tags: vuejs3

In Vue 2 I made dynamic calls like so:

```
this[someDynamicVariableWhichResolvesToAMethodName]();
```

How would I do this in Vue3 since there is no 'this'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Using non-arrow function

Declaring a method as a non-arrow function gives you back access to `this`

```js
function callthis(methodName) {
  this[methodName]();
}
```

#### 2. Wrapping methods inside an object

Methods wrapped in an object lets you call them dynamically

```js
<script setup>
const callit = (methodName) => {
  methods[methodName]();
};

const methods = {
  testMethod: () => {
    console.log('success');
  }
};
</script>
```

#### 3. Options API

The Options API is still available to you in Vue 3, which gives you back access to `this`, allowing you to write your component like you would with Vue 2